# Polygon with hole in react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-native

I'm using tomchentw/react-google-maps integration component, in according with Maps JavaScript API, I've try to put inside **paths** prop of **Polygon** component an array of outerCoords and InnerCords, to show holes inside polygon:

```
props.zones.value.data.map( () => {
    var outerCoords = [
      {lat: -32.364, lng: 153.207}, // north west
      {lat: -35.364, lng: 153.207}, // south west
      {lat: -35.364, lng: 158.207}, // south east
      {lat: -32.364, lng: 158.207}  // north east
    ];

    var innerCoords1 = [
      {lat: -33.364, lng: 154.207},
      {lat: -34.364, lng: 154.207},
      {lat: -34.364, lng: 155.207},
      {lat: -33.364, lng: 155.207}
    ];

    var innerCoords2 = [
      {lat: -33.364, lng: 156.207},
      {lat: -34.364, lng: 156.207},
      {lat: -34.364, lng: 157.207},
      {lat: -33.364, lng: 157.207}
    ];

    return (

      <Polygon
        key={zone.id}
        paths={[outerCoords, innerCoords1, innerCoords2]}
        onClick={props.onMapClick}
      />

    );
})
```

The result is a polygon with inside other polygons, not holes.

Did somebody else find this issue?

[image: render]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Maps JavaScript API documentation says the following:

> To create an empty area within a polygon, you need to create two paths, one inside the other. To create the hole, **the coordinates defining the inner path must be in the opposite order** to those defining the outer path. For example, if the coordinates of the outer path are in clockwise order then the inner path must be counter-clockwise.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_hole

In your example you should change the order for inner paths:

```
<Polygon
    key={zone.id}
    paths={[outerCoords, innerCoords1.reverse(), innerCoords2.reverse()]}
    onClick={props.onMapClick}
  />
```

**Proof of concept**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: -34.198173, lng: 151.677246},
  });

  var outerCoords = [
    {lat: -32.364, lng: 153.207}, // north west
    {lat: -35.364, lng: 153.207}, // south west
    {lat: -35.364, lng: 158.207}, // south east
    {lat: -32.364, lng: 158.207}  // north east
  ];

  var innerCoords1 = [
    {lat: -33.364, lng: 154.207},
    {lat: -34.364, lng: 154.207},
    {lat: -34.364, lng: 155.207},
    {lat: -33.364, lng: 155.207}
  ];

  var innerCoords2 = [
    {lat: -33.364, lng: 156.207},
    {lat: -34.364, lng: 156.207},
    {lat: -34.364, lng: 157.207},
    {lat: -33.364, lng: 157.207}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon, including both paths.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [outerCoords, innerCoords1.reverse(), innerCoords2.reverse()],
    strokeColor: '#FFC107',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FFC107',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I hope this helps!